# How to get selected item value with dropdown menu from another class in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu

I'm new to flutter and I was trying to get selected item with dropdown menu from another class. I'am gonna set the data as status to firestore. How can i reach selected item from another class?
I'm new to flutter and I was trying to get selected item with dropdown menu from another class. I'am gonna set the data as status to firestore. How can i reach selected item from another class?

This is my code.

dropdown_menu.dart

```
const List<String> list = <String>[
 'item1',
 'item2'

];


class DropdownButtonExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const DropdownButtonExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DropdownButtonExample> createState() => _DropdownButtonExampleState();
}

class _DropdownButtonExampleState extends State<DropdownButtonExample> {
  String dropdownValue = list.first;
  String holder = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValue,
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      elevation: 16,
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.blueGrey),
      underline: Container(
        height: 2,
        color: Colors.orangeAccent,
      ),
      onChanged: (String? value) {
        // This is called when the user selects an item.
        setState(() {
          holder = value!;
        });
      },
      items: list.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

form.dart

```
class Candidateaddform extends StatefulWidget {
  const Candidateaddform({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Candidateaddform> createState() => _CandidateaddformState();
}

class _CandidateaddformState extends State<Candidateaddform> {
  var candidate = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('testdata').doc();
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Aday Formu'),
          leading: IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context)
                  .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(homeRoute, (contex) => false)

              )),
      body: Column(
          DropdownButtonExample(),
          SizedBox(height: 24),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: (addData),
            child: Text('Save'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
Future addData() async {
    await testdata.set({
      'status' : '',
      'updatedate': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    }).then((value) => print('added.'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Form.dart**

```
class Candidateaddform extends StatefulWidget {
  const Candidateaddform({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Candidateaddform> createState() => _CandidateaddformState();
}

class _CandidateaddformState extends State<Candidateaddform> {
  /////
  final ValueNotifier<String?> dropDownNotifier = ValueNotifier(null);
  ////
  var candidate = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('testdata').doc();
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Aday Formu'),
          leading: IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context)
                  .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(homeRoute, (contex) => false)

              )),
      body: Column(
          DropdownButtonExample(valueNotifier:dropDownNotifier),
          SizedBox(height: 24),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: (addData),
            child: Text('Save'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
Future addData() async {
    await testdata.set({
      'status' : '',
      'updatedate': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    }).then((value) => print('added.'));
```

**dropdownmenu.dart**

```
const List<String> list = <String>[
 'item1',
 'item2'

];


class DropdownButtonExample extends StatefulWidget {
  final ValueNotifier<String?> valueNotifier;
  const DropdownButtonExample({Key? key,required this.valueNotifier}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DropdownButtonExample> createState() => _DropdownButtonExampleState();
}

class _DropdownButtonExampleState extends State<DropdownButtonExample> {
  String dropdownValue = list.first;
  String holder = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValue,
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      elevation: 16,
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.blueGrey),
      underline: Container(
        height: 2,
        color: Colors.orangeAccent,
      ),
      onChanged: (String? value) {
        // This is called when the user selects an item.
        setState(() {
          holder = value!;
        });
        valueNotifier.value = value!;
      },
      items: list.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
           onTap: (){
              valueNotifier.value = value;
              valueNotifier.notifyListener();
             }
```

and use dropDownNotifier.value to get selected item in form.dart

Comment: thanks for help, valueNotifier.value = value!; should be variable in dropdownmenu.dart ? actually which value gives me result? @rasityilmaz

Comment: We create a variable on the first page and pass it to the dropdown page, where data is filled in and you use this data on the first page.

use this variable for value => dropDownNotifier.value

Comment: i couldn't get selected value sorry, can you make sure to onChanged part?

Comment: Try importing DropDownItem with onTap I edited the answer